# New soldering tip doesn't screw in to iron

Tags: soldering

I just got new soldering tip pack, only to find out that they don't have a groove at the back, but that's how my iron accepts it. So I figured they were useless but I'll take a final shot at it and try to find out exactly how these tips attach to the iron cause I can't for the life of me figure it out, it's just a hole with nothing inside, I figure it clips on or something. Your views on how exactly this attaches to the iron would be appreciated.

Images here:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: That type of tip is supposed to be secured with a set-screw. Next time you buy a replacement tip for your iron, make sure you get one designed for the iron you have.

Comment: I didnt quite understand how a set screw would work here, and as I couldn't find anything about this anywhere else,jt would be a great help if you could direct me somewhere or something like that

Comment: @pranay: So you are saying that you dont know where a set screw would fit in into your iron, which was not designed to work with one? yeah...

Comment: I'm asking how the set screw type irons attach not how it attaches to my iron

Comment: @pranay you never told us what kind of iron you have. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: @derstrom8 *** to find out that they don't have a groove at the back, but that's how my iron accepts it. ***

Comment: If anyone is down voting at least give a reason for it...

Comment: @pranay I think it's pretty clear why people are downvoting. You have not given enough information for anyone to really help you. Simply saying "They have a groove in the back" does not give us information about your iron. WE NEED A MAKE AND MODEL NUMBER! Maybe you should do some research first before complaining on EESE about something that you could easily have avoided in the first place.

Comment: There is no standard tip design between soldering iron manufacturers, or even within one manufacturer (Weller uses several different tip/iron interfaces).  If you want new tips for your iron, you must be sure the tips you order are for your specific model of soldering iron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you got a tip for an iron like this one:

[image]

If you look, you will see that there's a sleeve that screws onto the grip.  Under the sleeve is the heating element.

The hole in the end of the tip you ordered goes over the heating element, then the sleeve screws on over it to hold it all together.